# Using setTimeout in React functional component in useCallback and useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, settimeout

I have been trying to use setTimeout in react to make a Popper component disappear off of the user screen. The Popper is set to appear after the user clicks a button. The visibility of the Popper component is tied to the "popperOpen" state below.

I have tried putting the setTimeout method inside of the callback function of the relevant button and also in a useEffect with no dependency array (both shown below). In the former, the Popper disappears immediately. In the latter, the Popper never disappears. Not shown below, but I have also tried useEffect with "popperOpen" in the dependency array.

What would be the proper way to get the desired functionality? And more fundamentally, how should I think about setTimeout in the context of react? (i.e., constant re-renders).

**setTimeout in useCallback**

```
const shareRef = useRef()
const [popperOpen, setPopperOpen] = useState(false);
const [anchor, setAnchor] = useState(shareRef.current)

useEffect(() => {
    setAnchor(shareRef.current);

   }, [shareRef])


const onShare = useCallback(() => {
    const id = window.location.pathname.split('/')[2]
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(window.location.origin + "/share/" + id)
    setPopperOpen(true)
    console.log("popper open")
    const timeout = setTimeout(()=>{setPopperOpen(false)},1000)
    console.log(timeout)
    return(()=>{clearTimeout(timeout)})
  },[setPopperOpen])


return(
        <Button startIcon={<BiShare />} onClick={onShare} ref={shareRef}>
          Share
        </Button>

      <Popper anchorEl={anchor} open={popperOpen} placement='bottom'>
        Pressed Button!
      </Popper>
)
```

**setTimeout in useEffect**

```
const shareRef = useRef()
const [popperOpen, setPopperOpen] = useState(false);
const [anchor, setAnchor] = useState(shareRef.current)

useEffect(() => {
    setAnchor(shareRef.current);

   }, [shareRef])


const onShare = useCallback(() => {
    const id = window.location.pathname.split('/')[2]
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(window.location.origin + "/share/" + id)
    setPopperOpen(true)
    console.log("popper open")
  },[setPopperOpen])

  

useEffect(()=>{
    const timeout = setTimeout(()=>{setPopperOpen(false)},1000)
    console.log(timeout)
    return(()=>{clearTimeout(timeout)})
  },[])


return(
        <Button startIcon={<BiShare />} onClick={onShare} ref={shareRef}>
          Share
        </Button>

      <Popper anchorEl={anchor} open={popperOpen} placement='bottom'>
        Pressed Button!
      </Popper>
)
```

Comment: Pass a function to `setTimeout`, you are passing the result of calling the function - `setTimeout(() => {setPopperOpen(false)},10000)`

Comment: Edited, thanks for flag! Same issue is happening unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem I've run into often when trying to use state setters as callbacks to other asynchronous/event-driven functions like `addEventListener`. My understanding of the problem is that due to the nested functions, a closure is being created around the initial value of `setPopperOpen`, so when that value is invoked later on, it is no longer equal to the latest `setPopperOpen` (because that variable is reassigned upon each re-render).

My solution has been to create a variable outside of the scope of your component, at the level of the module, for example `let _setPopperOpen`. Then, inside of your component, set `_setPopperOpen = setPopperOpen` (not in a `useEffect` or anything, just at the top level of your component). Finally, inside of your `setTimeout`, invoke the function `_setPopperOpen`, rather than `setPopperOpen`

Comment: This is it for working with the callback version of the above! Thanks for the context around the closure